# Replace all substring from a string only if substring is a whole word

Tags: java, string

I have tried writing a java code to replace a substring from a string only if that substring is a whole world. As for example, suppose that input string inputString = "abc ab bcd ab abcd" and I want to replace all substring "ab" to "xyz" such that output string looks like outputString = "abc xyz bcd xyz abcd". How to achive that? 
Here what I have tried:

```
public class TestReplace{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "abc ab bcd ab abcd";
        if(str.contains("ab")){
            str = str.replaceAll("ab", "xyz");
        }
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Output: `xyzc xyz bcd xyz xyzcd`. I know why this output comes but, I want output as `abc xyz bcd xyz abcd`. Appreciate help.

Comment: @lucumt You don't need to delete your answer. This is fine. If you undel it I upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replacing "ab" by "xyz", try replacing " ab " with " xyz " (so add spaces):

```
String str = "abc ab bcd ab abcd";
if(str.contains(" ab ")){
    str = str.replaceAll(" ab ", " xyz ");
}
System.out.println(str);
```

That will work if the code doesn't start or end with the word, but it will not replace the word if it is at the beginning of the string or at the end (because it doesn't have a space before or after it). For that you need to add and remove those spaces:

```
String str = "abc ab bcd ab abcd";
str = " " + str + " ";
if(str.contains(" ab ")){
    str = str.replaceAll(" ab ", " xyz ");
}
str = str.substring(1, str.length());
System.out.println(str);
```

That will first add spaces on both sides on the string, perform the replace, and then remove those spaces.